# How to store environment variables

Tags: python, windows, registry, environment-variables

To set an environment variable using Windows Command Processor ( `cmd`) :

```
SET MY_VARIABLE=c:\path\to\filename.txt
```

`MY_VARIABLE` now can be accessed by Python application started by same `cmd` window:

```
import os
variable = os.getenv('MY_VARIABLE')
```

I wonder if there is a way to set an environment variable from inside of Python so it becomes available to other processes running on the same machine?
To set a new environment variable:

```
os.environ['NEW_VARIABLE'] = 'NEW VALUE'
```

But this `NEW_VARIABLE` is lost as soon Python process and exited.

Comment: If your Python script *starts* those other processes, trivially and portably. If there's no parent/child relationship... well, you can persist them to the Windows registry to have them set for other processes at startup time, if that's what you want, but you should probably tag your question as Windows-specific in that case.

Comment: When a process updates the environment variables stored in the registry, it should broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message to tell Explorer to reload its environment variables. Any other process with a top-level window that cares to listen can do the same when it sees this message. Console processes such as cmd.exe generally don't own a window (the console window is owned by conhost.exe), so they generally don't get this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store environment variables persistently in the Windows registry. Variables can be stored for the current user, or for the system:

**Code to persistently set an environment variable on Windows:**

```
import win32con
import win32gui
try:
    import _winreg as winreg
except ImportError:
    # this has been renamed in python 3
    import winreg

def set_environment_variable(variable, value, user_env=True):
    if user_env:
        # This is for the user's environment variables
        reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(
            winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
            'Environment', 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
    else:
        # This is for the system environment variables
        reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(
            winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment',
            0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)

    if '%' in value:
        var_type = winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ
    else:
        var_type = winreg.REG_SZ
    with reg_key:
        winreg.SetValueEx(reg_key, variable, 0, var_type, value)

    # notify about environment change    
    win32gui.SendMessageTimeout(
        win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 
        'Environment', win32con.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000)
```

**Test code to invoke above:**

```
set_environment_variable('NEW_VARIABLE', 'NEW VALUE')
```

Answer (score -3):

Would a simple if not perhaps slightly crude way of doing this be simply to use os.system and pass the command through that as if you were running it in CMD?

An example being `os.system("SET MY_VARIABLE=c:\path\to\filename.txt")`

Hope that helps.`

Comment: That will do absolutely nothing but waste time.  The `SET` command only affects the child process, which immediately exits.

Comment: Okay, okay. As I suggest in my answer I was not entirely sure and was not in a position to check at the time but thought it might possibly at least point  OP in the right direction.