# How to update environment variables in Windows

Tags: python, windows

To create a new Windows Environment variable I go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced tab > Environment Variables and click `New...` button:

[image]

After `OK` is clicked and a `NEW_VARIABLE` is created I verify it is readable by Python process:

```
import os
value = os.getenv(`NEW_VARIABLE`)
print value
```

which prints:

```
NEW_VALUE
```

After exiting Python session and returning to Control Panel I use the same `Environment Variables` dialog where I delete `NEW_VARIABLE`.

Interesting that if now I would run Python's `print os.getenv('NEW_VARIABLE')` it would still return the same `NEW_VALUE` just like it still exists.
How to make sure the deleted Environment variable is not accessible by Python?

Comment: Did you restart the shell/cmd after deleting the variable, Wondering if there's some sort of cache going on here.

Comment: I don't know if this really matters, but do you initiate python from the same console or you do open a new cmd/idle/whatever? May be applications inherit the environment and changes only apply to future created processes...

Comment: I tried it using python shell and it works as expected after closing/restarting the shell. Like the others say, if you use cmd and you dont close the cmd too, it wont work because it's cached

Comment: I explained how this works in a comment on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969136).